# Removing folder named ~

Tags: bash, rm

This is the output of `ls -l`

```
ls -l
total 53484
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     4096 2011-02-10 05:59 ~
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 54313810 2011-02-13 05:09 jobs.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   384035 2011-02-15 05:33 jobsLog.out
```

I can't do `rm -rf ~`  because that will remove my home directory.

What should I do? Its not a problem for me, but just an eye-sore.

Comment: I'd avoid writing `rm -rf` on something with such potential for failure if you mis-type. Consider entering your `./~` folder and removing its contents from there before moving up a directory and running `rmdir ./~` to remove the ~ directory itself.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`rm -R ./~`

That will make it look for `~` in the current folder.

Comment: wow, way to look at things straight! kudos!

Comment: This answer is correct, but I think Oli's answer is better because it is safer.  If you slightly mistype this command, you will permanently trash your system.

Answer (score 44):

I've made silly mistakes with `rm` before so here are a few tips I've learnt over the years to try and keep you data safe from accidents:

1. Use a graphical solution like Nautilus. Soft-delete it to the trash. Then when you know you haven't moved your `$HOME` into the trash (everything would have started crashing and looking funky), empty your trash.
2. Move instead of delete. Rename the directory with `mv`, eg:

   ```
   mv ./\~ ./a-nice-sensible-directory-name
   ```

   Then delete it.
3. If in doubt, use the `-i` flag when dealing with potential fubars. It will prompt you for every file removed and should let you very quickly know if something bad is going to happen.

   ```
   oli@bert:~/Desktop$ rm -rfi ./del/
   rm: descend into directory `./del'? y
   rm: remove regular file `./del/output2.pdf'?
   ```

Comment: cant GUI, its a ssh terminal :P Good idea about the `mv`. I think I should make the rm alias with a `rm -i`.

Comment: You can bung `ssh://user@ip/folder` into nautilus. Doesn't work for everything (eg if you need to sudo), but there you go. Aliasing `-i` is a double-edged sword. It's helpful but it's also vastly irritating when you do lots of files. Consider `-I` too. And look at `man rm` for more tips.

Comment: +1 for the move idea. Now I wonder why there isn't a drop-in replacement for `rm` that moves to (say) ~/.Trash.

Answer (score 19):

Brilliant problem :)

You can delete the directory by [[image] escaping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) the tilde:

```
rm -rf \~
```

This works for all sorts of special characters.

Answer (score 17):

You can simply cake the folder name into apostrophes:

```
 rm '~'
```

Answer (score 6):

Just another, a little more complex, way to do it is using inode numbers:

```
$ ls -li
total 24
 7146369 drwxr-xr-x   4 user  staff   136 Jan 19 21:50 ~
$ find . -xdev -inum 7146369 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Pros

- It works with wathever fancy name you can have.
- Should be *safe* because inode numbers are unique (`-xdev`: Don't descend directories on other filesystems) and you can test the search first, just in case, removing `-exec rm -rf {} \;`.

Cons

- Doing `find .` in a directory with a lot of files and/or directories will take a lot of time, and disk reading.

Comment: I was always interested in inodes, and was wondering whether it was possible to do it =)

Comment: Of course, this only works if your current filesystem has the concept of an inode (not all the filesystems Ubuntu supports have this concept -- though most of those that do not are not native Unix filesystems like vFat and NTFS)