# Unable to remove a file which has a name like a command argument

Tags: command-line, rm

I inadvertently created a file called `-r` in my home directory. Now I cannot get rid of it:

```
rm -rf
rm: missing operand
Try 'rm --help' for more information.
```

Other attempts:

```
rm /-/r
rm: cannot remove ‘/-/r’: No such file or directory
```

Another one:

```
rm \-r
rm: missing operand
Try 'rm --help' for more information.
```

Is there a way to remove this file without deleting the whole directory?

Comment: Just FYI: Your second try using the forward slashes would delete a file named `r` from a directory named `-` in the root directory.

Comment: From `man rm`: To remove a file whose name starts with a -, 'for example -foo', use one of these commands: `rm -- -foo` or `rm ./-foo`

Comment: Related: [Removing folder named ~](http://askubuntu.com/questions/26466/removing-folder-named), [Unable to “rm” a file named “() - .” due to “No such file or directory”](http://askubuntu.com/questions/225055/unable-to-rm-a-file-named-due-to-no-such-file-or-directory), [rm file '??q:q '](http://askubuntu.com/questions/389138/rm-file-qq)

Comment: For future reference: [This question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/147377/49168) has answers for all the different possibilities to remove files. There are quite a few...

Comment: https://www.techpond.in/rm-invalid-option

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In this case you have to use the double-dash (`--`) in your command arguments.

The purpose of it is to tell to the command that what's follow has not to be taken as an argument to the command but a simple input. In the case of **rm**, a file or directory name.

So type `rm -- -r` and you should get rid of this file.

Answer (score 45):

There are many ways of doing this:

1. Use the `--` which signifies the end of option flags and the beginning of the list of arguments for many programs (including `rm`).

   ```
   rm -- -r
   ```
2. Use the full path

   ```
   rm /home/you/directory/-r
   ```

   or, from the same directory (your current directory is referred to as `.`):

   ```
   rm ./-r
   ```
3. Use `find`

   ```
   find . -name "-r" -exec rm {} \;
   ```

   or, to get all such files

   ```
   find . -name "-*" -exec rm {} \;
   ```
4. Use an ugly hack. Move everything to a different directory (this will fail for the `-r` file for the same reason as `rm` does) and then delete the original directory (which will remove the file) and move everything back again. So, assuming your `-r` file is in `~/foo`:

   ```
   $ mkdir ~/bar
   $ for f in *; do mv "$f" ../bar/; done
   mv: invalid option -- 'r'
   Try 'mv --help' for more information.
   $ rm -rf ~/foo
   $ mkdir ~/foo && cd ~/foo
   $ mv ~/bar/* .
   $ rmdir ~/bar
   ```

Comment: For the third option, `find . -name "-r" -delete` is even shorter. You may also want to use `-maxdepth 1` if you only want to delete the offending file in the current directory, but not recursively in all sub-directories.

Comment: @MalteSkoruppa true, I tend to avoid GNU-only options but there's no reason to on this site.

Answer (score 9):

You can also delete such files (starting with a '-') with this command:

```
rm ./-r
```

See the rm man page:

> To  remove a file whose name starts with a '-', for example '-foo', use
>       one of these commands:
>
> ```
> rm -- -foo
>
> rm ./-foo
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Or you could specify the full path of the directory in the `rm` command,

Example:

```
rm -rf ~/Desktop/-r
```